# How to COMPLETELY hide console in a Win32 program?

Tags: windows, winapi, console, windows-console

With the code below, the console is hidden BUT it appears for about 1 second.

How can I completely hide the console ?

```
#define _WIN32_WINNT 0x0500
#include <windows.h>
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

int WINAPI WinMain(HINSTANCE hInstance, HINSTANCE hPrevInstance, LPSTR cmdLine, int cmdShow){

HWND hWnd = GetConsoleWindow();
ShowWindow( hWnd, SW_HIDE );

MessageBox(NULL, TEXT("Hello!"), TEXT("yuhuuu"), 0);
return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Something is weird with your compiler settings. (You did not specify your compiler so I'm assuming MSVC)

The [WinMain](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms633559%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) entry point function from your example is used by GUI applications (Linker switch [/SUBSYSTEM](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/fcc1zstk%28v=vs.80%29.aspx):WINDOWS) and those applications don't get a console unless you call AllocConsole.

If you link with /SUBSYSTEM:CONSOLE then Windows will create a console for the process before your code is executed but a normal entry point for those applications is the plain old [main](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/3ze4ytsc%28v=vs.80%29.aspx) function.

Are you forcing the entry point with the /ENTRY switch? Either way, make sure the /SUBSYSTEM switch and the entry point function definition are compatible and match the type of application you want to create (GUI or console)

Comment: Code::Blocks is a IDE and not a compiler and it supports both MinGW/GCC and MSVC...

Comment: ops... How can I know what compiler I am using ?

Comment: In settings is selected "GNU GCC Compiler"

Comment: Ok I have found it. It's MinGW.

Comment: I am not forcing nothing... so are there any reason ?

Comment: I'm guessing the switch you want is [-mwindows](http://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc-4.7.0/gcc/i386-and-x86_002d64-Windows-Options.html#i386-and-x86_002d64-Windows-Options) and/or possibly -Wl,--subsystem,windows. See http://gcc.gnu.org/ml/gcc-help/2004-01/msg00225.html And I believe console is the default for GCC while MSVC tries to detect it based on the entry function...